# Calling functions between 2 classes

Tags: class

Class `myIOT2` contains a function that need to be called from class `IPmonitoring`:

```
bool myIOT2::checkInternet(char *externalSite, byte pings)
{
    return Ping.ping(externalSite, pings);
}
```

This function is needed as a pinger in `IPmonitor`:

```
void IPmonitoring::start(cb_func ping)
{

        _ping_cb = ping;
}
```

and this `cb_func` is defined by (inside `IPmonitor.h`):

```
typedef bool (*cb_func)(char *externalSite, byte pings);
cb_func _ping_cb;
```

inside my sketch (relevant parts only) I fail when `iot.checkInternet` is passed, while using a function `test` that calls `iot.checkInternet` succeeds:

```
myIOT2 iot;
IPmonitoring WiFi_service(ROUTER_IP, "Router");

bool test(char *a, byte b)
{
        bool x = iot.checkInternet(ROUTER_IP);
        return x;
}

void setup()
{
WiFi_service.start(iot.checkInternet); // <---- Trial a)fails
WiFi_service.start(test);              // <-----Trail b)succeeds
}
```

error is :

```
home/guy/Documents/git/Arduino/IPmonitor/IPmonitor.ino: In function 'void setup()':
IPmonitor:436:45: error: no matching function for call to 'IPmonitoring::start(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
         WiFi_service.start(iot.checkInternet);//
                                             ^
/home/guy/Documents/git/Arduino/IPmonitor/IPmonitor.ino:436:45: note: candidate is:
In file included from /home/guy/Documents/git/Arduino/IPmonitor/IPmonitor.ino:2:0:
/home/guy/Documents/git/Arduino/libraries/myIPmonitor/myIPmonitor.h:42:10: note: void IPmonitoring::start(IPmonitoring::cb_func)
     void start(cb_func ping);
          ^
/home/guy/Documents/git/Arduino/libraries/myIPmonitor/myIPmonitor.h:42:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'IPmonitoring::cb_func {aka bool (*)(char*, unsigned char)}'
Multiple libraries were found
```

What is done wrong ? and why `test` succeeds ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a method pointer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/82209/passing-a-method-pointer)

Comment: @Juraj No :( I didn't

Comment: @Juraj - mostly because Passing `test` succeeds

Comment: did you read that answer to the end?

Comment: @Juraj yes, but almost from start I fail to understand

Comment: the core of the problem is that a class method compiled has the object as first parameter so the parameters of the callback function don't match for `cb_func`

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental difference between a simple function and a function that is a member of a class.  You can't use a function pointer to point to a member function of a class: simply because that member function also includes information about the class instance that it belongs to.

The *proper* C++ way to handle it is to use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), but the Arduino AVR compiler lacks the full STL (Standard Template Library), so that can't be used on normal Arduinos. Other cores do have it, so you may well be able to use it on the ESP8266.

If you want to make your code portable between systems that may not have the full STL then there's other tricks you have to do:

- Use a wrapper function (which as you have found works), or
- Make a polymorphic class and store a pointer to the instance cast to the parent class - the parent class defines the functions that are allowed to be called from the pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much for a comprehensive explanation. A) it is an ESP8366. B) wrapper function is needed for which one my member functions? C) can you please write or direct for such example ? I must say it is a bit vague for me.

Comment: The "wrapper function" is a simple function that calls the function in the object you want. Your "test" function from your example. Something like `void test() { myObject.someFunction(); }` - I use something similar [here](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/Mesh/blob/master/nRF24L01/nRF24L01.cpp#L3)